# Find the particular solution to the Cauchy problem (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $y(x)$ be a continuous function $y(x)>0$ over the support $x>0$.

let $y'(x)$ be the first order derivative of $y(x)$.

Solve the Cauchy problem:

$$y'(x)y(x) = a(x)y(x) + b(x)$$

$$y(x_0) = y_0$$

where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are continuous, positive non zero functions and $x_0$, $y_0$ are positive constant real values.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $y(x)=\dfrac{1}{u(x)}$ ,

Then $y'(x)=-\dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)^3}=\dfrac{a(x)}{u(x)}+b(x)$

$u'(x)=-b(x)u(x)^3-a(x)u(x)^2$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2